# unexpectedly website returns redirection to itself

Tags: curl, redirect, wget

There is a website which returns status code 200 using curl. 
When I log in to my server via ssh and use the same curl statement then I get status code 302 with redirection to the same page I was requesting which finally results as "max redirects followed". What is more "wget" also get 302 as a response code.

Lets say the website I am talking about is "www.foo-bar.baz" which resolves to IP 000.00.000.00

```
curl -v http://www.foo-bar.baz

* Rebuilt URL to: www.foo-bar.baz/
*   Trying 000.00.000.00...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.foo-bar.baz (000.00.000.00) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.foo-bar.baz
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=0550ae88f472fe6e2c8771a2aca1968d; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0                
< Pragma: no-cache
< Location: http://www.foo-bar.baz/
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sun, 01 Mar 2020 10:52:58 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Server: LiteSpeed
< Connection: close
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: It probably wants that session cookie set, so you should probably consider adding `-b empty` to the command line so that the second request passes that on...

Comment: @DanielStenberg ```curl -b empty -v -L http://www.foo-bar.baz```  does not changes anything. The command ends with ```curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed```

Comment: It should change the subsequent requests to use cookies. I blame the server then.